# My computer is listed twice in the Network view; network shares are not accessible

Tags: windows-7, network-shares

I have a couple of network shares set up on my Win7 machine. They've been in constant use, from that same machine on which they're set up. One morning they just randomly stopped working:

[image]

When I went looking for what was wrong, I noticed that I also had my PC listed twice in the Network view in Explorer:

[image]

"Sirius" is the name of the PC on which these screenshots were taken.

I may have installed some windows updates around the time this happened. I have since tried rebooting and installing all the latest updates, to no avail. I've also removed the share in question and re-added it, making sure I give all rights to everyone. I'm an administrator on this machine, but I can't access the administrative shares (\\SIRIUS\c$) either, with the same message.

I *can* access \\localhost\AcronisImages and \\localhost\c$, and I *can* `ping sirius`.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you shut down your PC do both entries disappear or only one? If both: Do you have 2 network cards connected (including WiFi)? If only 1 disappears try switching off/on all machines (computers and routers) on the network.

Comment: @user I can't tell, because this bug only occurs on the computer that is duplicated. I only have one NIC.

Answer (score 1):

If feasible, it may be worth rolling back (via system restore) to see if there was a bad update. If so, there should be a fix searchable under its # - or it may install correctly the second time around.

Comment: Yeah, I think I'll have to. Fortunately (as you might guess from the path) I keep twice-weekly full-system images, so should be easy.

Comment: I'd much prefer to post a *real* answer, but it seems like one of those things that'll be 10x faster to solve with a sledgehammer... ;)

Answer (score 0):

Open the Command Prompt and run

```
ipconfig /flushdns
```